# Strange behaviour of delete dictionary operation on nested dictionary

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np

td={}
d = {}
for col in ['foo','bar','baz']:
    for row in ['a','b','c','d']:
        td.setdefault(row, np.random.randn())
        d.setdefault(col, td)

print d
del d['foo']['c']
print d
```

output:

```
{'baz': {'a': -1.6340274257732716, 'c': 0.6674016962534858, 'b': 2.0410088421902652, 'd': -1.2602923734811284}, 'foo': {'a': -1.6340274257732716, 'c': 0.6674016962534858, 'b': 2.0410088421902652, 'd': -1.2602923734811284}, 'bar': {'a': -1.6340274257732716, 'c': 0.6674016962534858, 'b': 2.0410088421902652, 'd': -1.2602923734811284}}
{'baz': {'a': -1.6340274257732716, 'b': 2.0410088421902652, 'd': -1.2602923734811284}, 'foo': {'a': -1.6340274257732716, 'b': 2.0410088421902652, 'd': -1.2602923734811284}, 'bar': {'a': -1.6340274257732716, 'b': 2.0410088421902652, 'd': -1.2602923734811284}}
```

Intention here is to delete only `d['foo']['c]`, but all the `'c'`'s are getting deleted across `'foo', 'bar', 'baz'` .. Not sure if this has been already answered on this forum, if yes please point me to that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting each value in `d` to reference the same copy of `td`. If you want the copies to be distinct, you'll need to create more than one `td` dictionary.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np

d = {}
for col in ['foo','bar','baz']:
    td = {}
    for row in ['a','b','c','d']:
        td.setdefault(row, np.random.randn())
    d.setdefault(col, td)

print d
del d['foo']['c']
print d
```

Comment: `for col in ['foo','bar','baz']:
    td={}
    for row in ['a','b','c','d']:
        td.setdefault(row, np.random.randn())
        d.setdefault(col, td)`